# Preventing django form to refresh whole page on submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-forms, bootstrap-modal

I have a form in Django which is embedded in a bootstrap modal element. The input of the form is a client id which I check if it is in the database. Everything works fine on submit except that in case the client id is not in the database the page gets reloaded and I have to open the modal element again to see the error message.

I tried to simple prevent the page refresh by adding a script to my html:

```
$('#modalform').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    })
```

But this breaks the form behaviour on submit.

The modal div with the form in my home.html looks like this:

```html
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="mymodal" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="" method="POST" id="modalform">
                    {% csrf_token %}

                    {% if form.non_field_errors %}
                        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                            {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                                {{ error }}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}

                    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ field.label_tag }}

                            {% if form.is_bound %}
                                {% if field.errors %}
                                    {% render_field field class="form-control is-invalid" %}
                                    {% for error in field.errors %}
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                            {{ error }}
                                        </div>
                                    {% endfor %}

                                 {% else %}
                                     {% render_field field class="form-control is-valid" %}
                                 {% endif %}
                             {% else %}
                                 {% render_field field  class="form-control" %}
                             {% endif %}
                         </div>
                     {% endfor %}

                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The view in view.py looks like this:

```py
def home(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("POST")
        form = SelectClient(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            url = reverse(
                "client",
                kwargs={"client_id": form.cleaned_data["client_id"]},
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)

    else:
        form = SelectClient()
        print("GET")

    return render(request, "app/home.html", {"form": form})
```

The form looks like this:

```py
class SelectClient(forms.Form):
    client_id = forms.CharField(label="Client ID")

    def clean_client_id(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data["client_id"]

        if Client.objects.filter(client_id=data).exists():
            print("Success!")
        else:
            print("No such client!")
            raise ValidationError(
                _("No such client!")
            )

        return data
```

And urls.py looks like this:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home, name="app-home"),
    path(
        "client/<str:client_id>",
        views.client,
        ),
]
```

1. Can I achieve that on submit of a client_id which is not in the database the page does not fully reload and just updates the error message without using ajax?
2. If not: How would the added ajax code look like, if I want the desired behaviour?

My first idea went to something like this:

```
$('#modalform').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/home/',
            data: {
                client_id: $('#client_id').val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
            },
            success: function () {
                alert("Client found, but what now?!");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Client not found, but what now?!")
            }
        })

    })
```

Comment: Do you see any error in your console? If yes then paste it.

Comment: If you want to use ajax, your view should check if `request.is_ajax()` and in that case return a `JsonResponse` (both for form valid and invalid) with in the dictionary returned a status code ('ok' or 'errors') and extra information to tell your script what to do: e.g. the url to redirect to in case of success, or the errors to show to the user.

Comment: Look [here](https://realpython.com/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/) for a good example on how to work with ajax requests.

Comment: @AakashTushar no error, because it is the expected behavior. I just want to change the behavior.

Comment: @dirkgroten I think i saw the `request.is_ajax()` method before. When I send back the mentioned JSON Response, what is the proper way to a) handle valid vs invalid case and b) to update the form if the response is invalid? Your mentioned link leaves that out (although it is a great resource!)

Comment: your json response should contain an 'errors' key (or status code key), in your success function you check if there are errors. And then update the form in place (replace div content) to show the errors.

Comment: I made it somehow work, but I am still struggling with updating the field errors for `{% for error in field.errors %}` above. How can I define field.errors['client_id'] in JS when I got the AJAX data with the message I want to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found it hard to work with Django Forms in this case, I solved the problem more explicitly.

My new `test_form` form:

```html
<form id="test_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="client_id">Client ID:</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="client_id" placeholder="Client ID" />
        <div class="form-text text-danger" id="form-error"></div>
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

My Javascript for the new `test_form` form:

```
$('#test_form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax/testform/',
            data: {
                client_id: $('#client_id').val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
            },
            success: function (data) {

                console.log(data["status"])
                if (data["status"] == "valid") {
                    window.location.href = "/client"
                }
                if (data["status"] == "invalid") {
                    $("#form-error").html(data["message"]);
                    $("#client_id").addClass("is-invalid")
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error!")
            }
        })

    })
```

And the new `testform` view:

```py
def testform(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SelectClient(request.POST)

        if request.is_ajax():
            if form.is_valid():
                data = {"status": "valid", "client_id": form.cleaned_data["client_id"]}

            else:
                data = {
                    "status": "invalid",
                    "client_id": form.data["client_id"],
                    "message": form.errors["client_id"],
                }
        else:
            data = {"message": "not an ajax call"}
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

Anything against this solution? Is this consider good practice?

Answer (score 1):

You want to check if there are form errors (you could do a specific field) and pop the modal if there are

```
<script>
    {% if form.errors %}
        document.getElementById("mymodal").showModal(); 
    {% endif %}
</script>
```

Comment: This is the easiest way to fix the problem, even though there is a page reload. If you want to avoid the page reload altogether and have a seamless experience within the modal, then using ajax is the way to go.

Comment: When using the code of @HenryM I get an error: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).showModal is not a function

Comment: because you gave your modal the id `mymodal` - I've amended

Comment: it works with `$("#mymodal").modal("show");` but as stated by @dirkgroten it reloads the page nevertheless

Comment: It'll reload the page because your error check is on the server.  You'll need to do an error check in JS if you don't want the page reload

Comment: @HenryM How to check similar as `if Client.objects.filter(client_id=data).exists()` in JS?

Comment: You can't. Use ajax as I said in my comment on your question. You started down the right path, you just need to change your view to return json and implement the success function.